# Sample blogging application (or any other same kind of application) tutorials using sencha touch, getting started kit

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

*PS:- I have seen first [20 screencasts](http://vimeo.com/12636777) for Sencha touch*

But, Most of them are very basic. They are good to know but not sufficient to know.

There is not a single application in examples which stores data on remote server, authenticate from remove server or anything like that. I am looking for some blogging tutorials or anything like that. Isn't there anything. I checked alot of questions on stackoveflow, Nothing. Nothing on sencha forum. Not even anything about MVC structure apart from a video.

All I have is there API docs with tons of functions. What I am supposed to do that. API docs are always for reference not digging each and every things from scratch.

I am trying from past 3 days and this is what i have right now in my hand.I am stuck. Something like rails guide will be awesome.

Is there any book? Apart from that Manning's which is in alpha phase..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was pretty good.  Unfortunately there is no part 2.  It's a "contacts" example so not the same as your blog, but should get you started.

http://mikehoitomt.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/sencha-touch-application-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1/

As far as authentication, you would authenticate the user on one login page then redirect to the sencha touch page with a cookie to authorize requests.

Sencha Touch is kinda like backbone.js so this tutorial may help you with the rails side.  http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/

Good luck, Sencha Touch is worth it your app will turn out great, ask questions if you need help.

Comment: Its quite useful. but i am still confused why there is not official documentation.. Just throwing out same kind of examples is totally useless.

Comment: I got by on the demos that came with the api and the api docs.  As far as the communication with a backend server it's all vanilla json/REST so if you can do json/REST you'll be fine.  But I can't tell you why they chose the demos/tutorials they did.

Comment: here is the part2  http://mikehoitomt.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/sencha-touch-application-with-ruby-on-rails-%E2%80%93-part-2/#comment-28

Comment: Also just got a reply from Sencha via twitter, they are working on it. http://tinypic.com/r/dzyxs0/7